# Playing status or costum status Discord Bot

Tags: discord.js, bots

I have trying any codes that i found on stack overflow and whole internet, no one working
here's my old codes (js 12) it's working before

```
client.on('ready', async () => {    console.log (`${client.user.tag} Im already online!`)      client.user.setActivty("Greatest status ever") })
```

srry if the question wasn't clear ._.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [setPresence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) you can modify the presence data with all that [options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData).

```js
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
```